how to aggregate values with multiple headers, both in rows and columns
https://kidb.adb.org/mrio#:~:text=ADB%20MRIO%20at%20Constant%202010%20Prices%20(2019)
Attached link is a global input-output database.  It comprised 63 countries and each country has 35 sectors.
First, I want to aggregate the countries along with their sectors (both rows and columns) as:
BRA, CAN, MEX, and ROW as "ROW"; AUS, TAP, KAZ, SRI, PAK, FIJ, BRU, BHU, KGZ, MLD as "ROA"; then,
retained these countries as is, PRC, JPN, KOR, BAN, CAM, HKG, INO, IND, LAO, MAL, MON, NEP, PHI, SIN, THA, VIE, US, GER; and then the rest of the countries as "EU".
Then aggregate all the sectors (both rows and columns) as "OTH", except for C4, C12, C13, C14 and C15 which are to be retained.
Then there are also F1, F2, F3. F4. F5 for each countries.
I want to aggregate the countries along with their Fs (both rows and columns) as:
BRA, CAN, MEX, and ROW as "ROW"; AUS, TAP, KAZ, SRI, PAK, FIJ, BRU, BHU, KGZ, MLD as "ROA"; then,
retained these countries as is, PRC, JPN, KOR, BAN, CAM, HKG, INO, IND, LAO, MAL, MON, NEP, PHI, SIN, THA, VIE, US, GER; and then the rest of the countries as "EU".
These are the codes I used:
<import numpy as np   import scipy as sp   import scipy.linalg as linalg  import pandas as pd  MRIO_org = pd.read_excel( 'ADB-MRIO-2021.xlsx' )  print( MRIO_org )
MRIO_org = pd.read_excel( 'ADB MRIO 2019.xlsx' ) print( MRIO_org )
##header = 6 => the data in row 6 (c1,c2,c3,・・・) as the column labels. 
##usecols=range(3,2525) ## => Read the data from the 3rd column to the 2524th column. ## MRIO_org1.set_index('Unnamed: 3')
=> Let the column data of “Unnamed:3” be index.
MRIO_org1 = pd.read_excel('ADB MRIO 2019.xlsx', header=6, usecols=range(3,2525))
MRIO_org2 = MRIO_org1.set_index('Unnamed: 3') print(MRIO_org2)
Specify Z, V, x, F Z_org = MRIO_org2.iloc[0 : 2205, 0 : 2205] V_org = MRIO_org2.iloc[2205 : 2212, 0 : 2205] x_org = MRIO_org2.iloc[2212 , 0 : 2205] F_org = MRIO_org2.iloc[0 : 2205, 2205 : 2520]
Data for changing country number
New number  col=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24, 25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47 ,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63]
#old number row
=[17,21,21,21,22,22,21,1,21,21,20,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,7,8,21, 21,2,26,21,21,21,22,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,21,17,18,4,10,13,1 5,16,17,11,17,17,7,9,17,17,17,5,17,12,14,6,22]
number of sectors in Z h=35 m=len(row) # number of old counties n=int(max(col)) # number of new countries agg=np.zeros((mh , nh)) # Aggregation Matrix for Z unit=np.identity(h) # Unit Matrix h x h for i in range(m):
agg[h*(col[i]-1) : h * col[i], h*(row[i]-1) : h*row[i]] = unit

number of Final Demand items g=5 agg2=np.zeros((mg, ng)) # Aggregation Matrix for F unit2=np.identity(g) # Unit Matrix g x g for i in range(m):
agg2[g*(col[i]-1) : g * col[i], g*(row[i]-1) : g*row[i]] = unit2

Aggregation Z_new =agg @ Z_org @ agg.T F_new =agg @ F_org @ agg2.T x_new =x_org @ agg.T V_new =V_org @ agg.T
Create New MRIO Table for Excel MRIO_new=np.zeros((2213,2521)) MRIO_new[0 : 2205, 0 : 2205] = Z_new MRIO_new[2205 : 2212, 0 : 2205] = V_new
MRIO_new[2212 , 0 : 2205] = x_new.T MRIO_new[0 : 2205, 2205 : 2520] = F_new MRIO_new[0 : 2205, 2520] = x_new
In[32]: df=pd.DataFrame(MRIO_new)
MRIO_new=df.to_excel('MRIO2019_new.xlsx')>

When you are done detailing what you want, don't forget to give at least as much detail on what you tried and what failed how exactly, because otherwise your post will continue giving the currently strong impression that you do not focus on a specific programming problem you encountered while trying yourself. [edit] and try for [ask]. Taking the [tour] should not hurt.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
